# Are there any electro-optic crystals that are also pyroelectric but not birefringent?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

As the title says, a crystal that is electr-optic and pyroelectric can it be non-birefrigent?

Answer (score 2):

No. Pyroelectric, piezoelectric, etc. crystals do not have inversion symmetry (or else they would not by pyroelectric, ...).  This reduced crystal symmetry implies that the axes are not equivalent, so birefringence will occur.